# How can I cache large docker images on new GKE nodes?

Tags: docker, caching, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When GKE creates a new node as part of its autoscaler, how can I ensure that this new node has fast access to a large docker image? One of the docker image size is 15GB and I have a deployment that uses that image. Would be nice to somehow cache this image onto new nodes so it doesn't have to be pulled every time a new node is launched!

Answer (score -1):

In such case I would recommend you to use [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs) as there is no mean to make your image automatically available locally on newly created worker nodes (e.g. appearing as a result of node autoscaling process). If you decide not to use **Container Registry**, you would need to take care of uploading such image manually to every newly created node and this can be a tedious task.

> Would be nice to somehow cache this image onto new nodes so it doesn't
>   have to be pulled every time a new node is launched!

So unfortunatelly it does have to be pulled at least once when a new node is launched. It may be cached after that i.e. once it was pulled the first time from **GCR**.

As you can read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images):

> The default pull policy is `IfNotPresent` which causes the Kubelet to
>   skip pulling an image if it already exists.

So you dont' have to do anythig specific to make sure your images are cached locally once they're already pulled as this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Hi, I would have to download this 15GB file from the internet each time - to every new node. I was hoping there is a way to share a volume with all nodes - download the 15GB image once and put it on a volume - and then every node created can copy this image to itself from this volume. OR some solution like this - that would avoid a 15GB download for every new node - which takes 5+ minutes - The goal was to get the new nodes ready as quickly as possible.

Comment: This is exactly the purpose of GCR. It allows you to store your image copy in one place in Google Cloud, so you don't have to download it from the Internet each time new node is created. Did you try it ? In my opinion it doesn't make sense to reinvent the wheel. However if you want you can create GCE Persistent Disk. It allows read-only access by many nodes at the same time so your image can be pulled from more than one node at a time. Are you sure you cannot reduce the image size ? 15GB is quite a lot for the docker image and maybe not all its current content should be really containerized.

Comment: GCR is the same as "the internet" there isn't a tangible difference here. This isn't a good answer!

Enabling image streaming on a cluster can improve speeds, but not by much.